# Is there a process name for islanders becoming unisolated?

Tags: war, trade, prehistory, exploration, travel

Basically I would like to know if there is an official term for the process which an independent island would undertake once reaching the point in societal/technological development to travel to other islands/land masses and end their isolation by interacting with other peoples through trade/war/etc.

Just to clarify, I mean the island's isolation ending due to the islanders themselves exploring the outside world, not other people landing on the island and colonising it (etc).

Comment: Apologies if this isn't the correct stack exchange to post this question, but it is the best I could find, if someone knows a better site to post the question then please let me know!

Comment: This looks mostly OK. I think you are conflating islands with the people that live on them ("islanders") though. Also, I suspect you might really want to know about isolated populations of people ("insular"?), rather that literally just people who live on islands. Also, you might have better luck with this question on the English Language and Usage stack (perhaps with the singe-word-requests tag).

Comment: Thank you very much TED, & I was actually ideally thinking of an island population making outside contact, but if the official term name is the same for insulated peoples in general making outside contact then that would be great.

Comment: Edited a smidge on that basis.

Comment: "Stablish communication channels/routes"? I doubt that you will find anything so specific that applies to islanders going out but not to non-islanders going in neither to non-islanders meeting non-islanders or a chance encounter at a McDonalds... additionally, usually islanders would not be truly isolated, because if they were the islands would not have been colonized in the first place (the only exception in which a culture arrived to an island and lost the ability to navigate that I heard of is the island of Pascua).

Comment: You might have more success at English.SE - but a good word would be "integration" maybe?

Comment: Perhaps "grew curious" or "became bolder".